# IEnumerable IEnumerator with and without Current moveNext reset

Tags: c#, .net, collections, ienumerable, ienumerator

I am trying to understand IEnumerable interface how it works but finding it difficult to understand the concept because some examples use IEnumerator, GetEnumerator, Current, moveNext, Reset and some examples demonstrate IEnumerable with IEnumerator without  Current,moveNext, Reset with nested inner class.

I need one simple example to understand this concept and when it's appropriate to use IEnumerator with Current, moveNext,Reset and when not.

Comment: Consuming? or implementing?

Comment: @MarcGravell. I would be grateful if you could kindly provide explanation from both point of views. Thanks

Comment: @MarcGravell. With .NET 4.5 I normally don't need to implement IEnumerator is that correct?

Comment: it isn't actually a .NET runtime feature; it is a compiler feature; IIRC, iterator blocks have been around since C# 2.0, and .NET 4.5 ships with a much higher compiler version than that, so : yes

Comment: @MarcGravell. when do we really need to consume IEnumerable?

Comment: `foreach` loops and certain LINQ methods are the most common way that you will consume `IEnumerable`. Extremely rarely do you need to actually do it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **virtually never** appropriate to use `Reset()`, since that method is explicitly not reliable: iterator blocks do not support it, for example. So there is very little point worrying about implementing it.

If you mean in terms of implementing it: most of the time, the most appropriate thing to do is to *use an iterator block* (aka `yield return`), because doing this by hand is hard, error-prone, and usually serves no great purpose. You would need to have something very specific in mind to warrant implementing an enumerator by hand.

Some examples you see may *pre-date when iterator blocks were addd to the language*; in which case, they had no option *except* to write an iterator by hand.

Most times: just let the compiler worry about the heavy lifting. `yield return` is your friend. Note: things like `List<T>` use a custom iterator that is value-typed etc to minimize impact; note that when you `foreach` over a `List<T>` you aren't even actually using `IEnumerable<T>` - you are just using the raw `GetEnumerator()` and associated APIs. `foreach` *can use* `IEnumerable<T>`, but it does not *require* it.

Answer (score 0):

PROVIDER ========

Here an example where i've splitted the class from the enumerator.
MyEnumerableClass is Enumerable so if someone needs to enumerate it, it can retrieve an enumerator on the class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;


class MyEnumerableClass : IEnumerable
{
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new MyEnumerableClassEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The enumerator is responsible to enumerate the elements on the class.
In this example, I did not this, I hope is more clear in this way.
In this example the class MyEnumerableClass and the enumerator on that class (MyEnumerableClassEnumerator) are not related. Usually the enumerator enumerates something contained in the class so the enumerator keeps a reference to the class. Also, if the state of the class changes "significantly", the enumerator could not enumerate it so it should raise InvalidOperationException. This behaviour usually is achieved adding a version identifier (i.e. int versionId) in the class. When the enumerator is istantiated it saves the versionId. If on a MoveNext call the enumerator sees that the versionId has changed it raises the exception.
In this way you can have several enumerators active on the same class at the same time.
Anyway, here the very simple example of an enumerator

```
class MyEnumerableClassEnumerator : IEnumerator
{
    int myStatusVariable = 0;

    public object Current
    {
        get { return myStatusVariable; }
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        return ++myStatusVariable < 10;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        myStatusVariable = 0;
    }
}
```

CONSUMERS ========
Now the consumers.
You can consume an anumerator in 2 ways, via Language (that generates interface calls) or generating calls by yourself

Here the examples based on the class above

```
        MyEnumerableClass myEnumerableClass = new MyEnumerableClass();

        foreach (var item in myEnumerableClass)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }


        IEnumerator enumerator = myEnumerableClass.GetEnumerator();
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);
        }
```